# MacBook Pro web browser windows cropped after resuming from sleep bug

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, google-chrome, firefox

I've been seeing this bug most recently in Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E46). It was in prior versions but I wasn't keeping track.

When I resume from sleep my browser windows are cropped in both Firefox and Chrome. Pretty much only the top left corner of the browser window is the view. I can resize the window but the scrollbars remain on this little ~640x480ish view.

The attached screenshot illustrates the issue. If I refresh the window the page resumes and consumes the full window size.

One way to get the window back to normal is to refresh, but I have to do that for every tab that is cropped (and not all windows/tabs are cropped). If I show and hide the bookmarks toolbar in Firefox all windows are fixed.

Any ideas? I can't find any other reports of this bug, but it's happened on two different MacBook Pros of mine. The most recent is: (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: A very interesting one. It only happens when resume from sleep mode? It is not web page related? It does not look like graphics problem related. It is not monitor or external monitor related?Do you use add ons on both browsers that could do that ? Could you look in the Console log for "Windowserver" and what setting does it set to for the display after wake up. (after "wake reason" log).

Comment: @Buscar웃SD it appears to be related to an external monitor. I'm not sure if it's any monitor but two separate Macs each with a different non-Apple monitor behave this way.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you look in the Console log at the time stamp of interest and typing "window" in the search box, then copy and report those here. It will tell us what your mac has chosen "windowserver" to use for the external monitor. There might be many lines with "windowserver" so copy them all.

Comment: I cleared the console, plugged in the external monitor and here are the lines of interest. https://gist.github.com/wsams/63070cb735cd89175485